# I'm looking for some help optimizing a part of a c# application that writes/reads datatables to files

Tags: .net, optimization, serialization, datatable, c#-2.0

any advice would be appreciated, I'm still learning in c# so I apologize if I miss something obvious. I'm using VS2010 and the application uses net 2.0

I'm looking to speed up these two processes as much as possible. The first process is reading in data tables from a server, then storing them as cache files. Each cache file has multiple data tables. The second part is retrieving these data-tables from a cache file and storing them in a dataset.

Originally the process stored the data tables as XML files, and this took forever both with creating the cache files and retrieving them. when running the application. These tables can range anywhere from 10MB to 400MB in size.

I set it up so it built and read the cache files to and from my local machine.

I tried using binary serialization, which helped a good amount. It took the tables down to about 1/6 the XML file size and also sped it up, but I'm looking to see if there is something faster. I have been looking for awhile now and I cannot find anything else. I checked out protobuf-net, which looks like a fantastic way to speed up serializing, but from what I found data tables do not seem work well with it.

Here are some numbers..

```
Time to build Cache files:
XML-about 2 hours, 
Binary -  about 1 hour

Test Case for reading from Cache file:
XML - 3m 40s, 
Binary - 2m 20s
```

I know this is a lot of data and can't expect a whole lot, but is there another way?

Comment: Why are you creating the cache files and then loading *them* into a DataSet?

Comment: @Mike The data tables are pulled from a non-local server. The cache folders are created on a local server then for use for the application. Then when the application is running it accesses the proper folders and then populates a dataset with the data tables in the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule of optimization is to measure where time is being spent.  It may be a good guess that the time is in the serialization code, but there's nothing like a good profiler session to be sure...

Having said that, the performance gains you see when changing the serialization mechanism do indicate that at least a chunk of time is spent on serialization itself.

XML Serializer is horribly slow for large files.  BinaryFormatter is better, but still not exactly a speed demon.

Protocol Buffers are around 6x faster and store data much more compact than BinaryFormatter.

http://theburningmonk.com/2011/08/performance-test-binaryformatter-vs-protobuf-net/

[image]

[Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) (of Stack Overflow) wrote an implementation of protocol buffers in .NET

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

You can get this using NuGet.

([Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) [did as well](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/), but I prefer Marc's implementation).

There is also

> A library for serializing ADO.NET DataTables and DataReaders into an efficient, portable binary format. Uses Marc Gravell's Google Protocol Buffers library, protobuf-net.

https://nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net-data/2.0.5.480

(Also available through NuGet)

Comment: Thanks! It was extremely easy to use protobuf-net-data and it did a good job improving the size of the files and the speed of the serializing/deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

First step for me in problems like this is to break out software such as [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) which are fantastic at profiling right the way down to the time it takes for individual method calls. You can also identify your stress points too, if an individual method is being called 10M times then shaving a few ms off it can result in massive savings.

I'd also suggest [taking a look at the execution plan](http://connectsql.blogspot.com/2011/03/sql-server-execution-plan-major-points.html) in SQL to determine if those can be optimised in any way and there are loads of articles on google for that.

Another option is to make use of the [C# stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), wrapping blocks of code with this may help identify the bottlenecks.

Comment: I love ANTS, but Visual Studio's built-in profiler is quite good now and also worth a mention.

Comment: True, depends on his VS edition though and I didn't want to get into that confusing mess :-s

Comment: Yeah.  Prior to VS 2010 the built-in one was not so awesome.

Comment: Thanks! I will try out ANTS and check out the SQL